# HP-G6-1117TX graphics issue with ubuntu 11.04 installation

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, amd-radeon, hp-laptop

i have laptop HP-G6-1117TX in which i have installed ubuntu 11.04 recently, the installation was fine with no error, wireless, display almost everything was fine for new install, i switched off the system after install.

when i on again after log screen just black screen appears, some times i hear logging sound.

i have tried to restart many times same problem exist, so installed again freshly by formating whole hard disk again. but same problem exist after reinstall.

i think my laptop graphics card creating problem,

> **Please Help Me to Install Ubuntu in HP-G6-1117TX**

i have listed my laptop specification

Model No - HP Pavilion g6-1117tx

Microprocessor  -  2.1 GHz Intel Core i3-2310M

Microprocessor Cache - 3 MB L3 cache

Operating System -  Genuine Windows 7 Home Basic 64

Memory -  3 GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Memory Max  - Upgradeable to 8 GB DDR3

Hard Drive  -  500 GB SATA (5400 rpm)

Display - 15.6" High-Definition LED HP BrightView Display (1366 x 768)

Video Graphics - AMD Radeon HD 6470M (1 GB DDR3 dedicated)

Multimedia Drive - SuperMulti DVD?R, RW with Double Layer Support

Network Card - Integrated 10, 100 BASE-T Ethernet LAN

Wireless Connectivity -  Bluetooth wireless networking Intel 802.11

Sound - Altec Lansing speakers - SRS Premium Sound

Keyboard - Notebook keyboard with home roll keys

Pointing Device - TouchPad supporting Multi-Touch gestures and On/Off button

Answer (score 0):

Due to some issues with 'X' upstream, booting Ubuntu from CD/USB on some graphics cards (mostly Nvidia and ATI) results in a black screen or a weird display with horizontal or vertical lines. Just as if there is no display output from the graphics card, or the resolution is not being read by the monitor. Actually, there is an output, but it is out of sync. In order to solve this, you need to pass the nomodeset boot parameter, or some other parameters listed at the end of this guide.

Live CD/USB Environment

Pop in your CD/USB and boot from it. As soon as the computer starts booting from the boot media, keep on pressing any key until you are presented with this page:

Once you see this page, press F6 and you'll see some boot options popping up. Navigate to the "nomodeset" entry and hit Enter. You'll see a mark in the beginning. Press and now choose "Try Ubuntu Without Installing" or "Install Ubuntu", whichever you want.

Hopefully, you'll see the desktop this time.

After your first boot, press 'e' while in the boot screen then check for 'quite splash' and replace it with "nomodeset" , u'll successfully login to ubuntu, after that check for the additional drivers .

Comment: This looks like a quote from somewhere else, please provide a link. You can use the formatting tools in the editor to mark the quotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the brightness.. same thing happened with me but the installation was Ubuntu 13.04